# Twilio returning SMS message to original sender

Tags: twilio

I have a web app that uses Twilio to facilitate members sending SMS to other members of the site. Currently, it's a one way communication and I want to change that. Here is my problem - because the messages are many-to-many, I don't know how to forward the response SMS to the correct sender. For example, member A goes to my site and sends SMS to members F - Z and, at roughly the same time, member B sends SMS to members C - H. Because some members (F - H) received two SMS from different members and respond to both, how do I forward the correct response to the original sender and not mix them up?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I guess you're using only the one number for this messaging. The best way to achieve this is to assign numbers per user that is sending messages this way. In your example, members A and B should get different numbers and that way, when member F responds to member A, they do so directly to A's number and it can be routed to A easily. There is no way to use one number for all your site members and allow them to direct replies to a particular user based on recent incoming messages.

Check out [this article on the Twilio site with more information on number pools and two way communication](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-have-users-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-twilio).

Comment: One way to think about it if your familiar with development is SMS is a stateless communication medium. I have looked at this before and there is really no good way to make it a stateful communication medium due to the limited number of characters allowed. First you would have to get users to remember to append an identifier to their message, even a simple one like xyz12 then only leaves 155 characters for communications.

Comment: Would using MMS help solve this issue? I'm trying to avoid buying a phone # for each member. That would significantly add to my costs.

Comment: MMS works the same way, so that won't help. Did you read the article in my answer? The bit at the bottom suggests how you could achieve this with a pool of numbers no bigger than the most connected user. So you don't need a number for every user.

Comment: I did read the article. I didn't see that as an answer to my particular problem. In my case, every member can SMS every other member with no limit and this is likely to happen (although it is not likely for all members to SMS all members at the same time, if that makes sense). So, it seems, that I would need to purchase a number for every member. I was trying to think of a way to use the media url of an MMS message as a cookie. If you can think of any other alternatives, please let me know. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: If everyone can message everyone else then you will need a number per user to distinguish between incoming messages. The thing is that there is no conversational meta data passed over SMS, there is no "in reply to" field. In fact, if you look at your SMS app on your phone, you'll see that for one number all you can do is send one message regardless of how many you've received, you can't choose to reply to a particular message. Perhaps you can share a few more details on your app and I might be able to help, drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com.